# Accessing data from Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have created this object :

```
    var hemicycle = {

    Groupe : "Group1" [{
        Member : [{
            Name : "MemberName",
            Siege : "SiegeNumber",
            Vignette : "PhotoURL"
        }]

    }]


};
```

I try to display some data from it but I can't access any.
When I type hemicycle in the dev tools of Chrome I get this :

[image]

I also tried to display "Group1" from the object but it won't let me, I typed this :

[image]

I don't know why my object is not defined ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [JavaScript (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript).  [Working with Objects (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Remove "Group1" (it's not valid declaration) should work.

Comment: Your object is invalid. Your `Groupe` should be object, but is *like* simple value, no `:` after `Group1`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is, that you actually don't have a valid object. `Groupe` has really weird structure, what is it supposed to be? Array? Then try this:

```
var hemicycle = {
  Groupe: [{
    Member : [{
      Name : "MemberName",
      Siege : "SiegeNumber",
      Vignette : "PhotoURL"
    }]

  }]
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed "Group1" and create a GroupName : "Group1" inside of Groupe. Working great right now !

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your object itself is invalid.
Two ways to improve that. Choose whatever fits your needs best.

```
var hemicycle = {

Groupe : "Group1",
Content : [{
    Member : [{
        Name : "MemberName",
        Siege : "SiegeNumber",
        Vignette : "PhotoURL"
    }]

}]
```

};

```
var hemicycle = {
    Groupe : [{
        Member : [{
           Name : "MemberName",
           Siege : "SiegeNumber",
           Vignette : "PhotoURL"
    }]

}]
```

};

Comment: Thanks, I managed to modify my array with the answer of Paulooze.

Comment: the most important thing is that you have learned something, not to whom the repu goes :D

Answer (score 0):

this simple example should solve your problem

```
var myObj = {
    "1": { address: "44 buxton gardens berea durban", lat: "25.686", lng: "58.1156"},
    "2": { address: "44 buxton gardens berea durban", lat: "0.0086", lng: "-0.00056"}
 }

  alert(myObj['1']['address']); //this get the address value of the first element

//using foreach statement to access the element and key

 for (key in myObj){
  alert(key); //this will display the 1
 //use can say
 alert(myObj[key]['address']); // this gets the value of address
 }
```